# How to specify SceneKit camera control rotation center?

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, appkit

I am writing a simple *SceneKit* point cloud viewer for macOS and using the built in [camera controls provided by `SCNView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1523171-allowscameracontrol). Initially I add the coordinate axes to the scene's root node which are placed at the origin and then I add a a camera at (4,4,4) pointed towards the origin (the y-axis the "up direction" by default):

```
cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 4, y: 4, z: 4)
cameraNode.look(at: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

I the enable the `SCNView`'s camera control:

```
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
```

The screenshot in the upper-left of the following figure shows the initial view:

[image]

Before I add anything else the camera control works as expected and the camera uses (0,0,0) as the center of rotation as I pan.

Later the app loads a point cloud and adds it to the scene graph (see screen shot in upper right):

```
let indices: [Int32] = Array(0..<Int32(vertices.count))
let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .point)
let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, colorSource], elements: [element])
let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, .pi) // yaxis up
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

The point cloud's origin is (0,0,0) (which should makes things simple). I do rotate the point cloud 180 degrees around the x-axis since the y-axis is pointing down in the model, but needs to be up for scene kit's default orientation. I reposition the camera, but it is still pointed at (0,0,0):

```
 let rad = 10.0
 let theta = Double.pi/4
 let phi = Double.pi/3

 let x = CGFloat(rad * cos(phi) * cos(theta))  // assume center at (0,0,0)
 let z = CGFloat(rad * cos(phi) * sin(theta))
 let y = CGFloat(rad * sin(phi))
 self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
 self.cameraNode.look(at: SCNVector3Zero)
```

Here is the weird part. If I immediately load the point cloud, the camera pans around some unknown point off to the left (see screenshot in lower left). If I interact with the camera *before* loading the point cloud (or sometimes just wait a bit or hold my tongue differently) the rotation center is the desired point (0,0,0) as shown on the bottom right.

Is there something else I need to specify to get the desired behavior? I try setting the
[camera controller's target](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontroller/2867539-target) to the origin

```
self.sceneView.defaultCameraController.target = SCNVector3Zero
```

to no avail. The docs are essentially empty. Am I missing something in my setup? The non-deterministic behavior seems to indicate I may be missing some other part of the API I should be invoking.

Answer (score 0):

### Set a camera `target` for orbit rotation

You're right, we must use camera's `target` instance property for orbit rotation in world space:

```
open var target: SCNVector3
```

Additionally, use `frameNodes()` instance method for a custom framing:

```
open func frameNodes(_ nodes: [SCNNode])
```

Do not forget to apply your brand-new camera. Here's how your code should look like:

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode             // IMPORTANT
```

---

```
let aimNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "torus", recursively: true)!
aimNode.position = SCNVector3(30, 7, 12)
aimNode.opacity = 0.1

sceneView.defaultCameraController.frameNodes([aimNode])
sceneView.defaultCameraController.target = SCNVector3(30, 7, 12)
// z-axis orientation compensator
sceneView.defaultCameraController.rollAroundTarget(-5)
```

Comment: Thanks ... this added a few more things to try. Alas the behavior is still non-deterministic. I only have a single camera so setting `pointOfView` doesn't change its behavior.

Comment: Ok. One more note – If you get rid of the `lookAt` constraint, then the camera should work as intended (i.e. more predictably).

Comment: Gave it a try. With no `lookAt` specification its view direction seems to be parallel with the horizontal plane.

Comment: What does `rollAroundTarget` do? It would be nice if the docs has some details.

Comment: Rotates camera about z axis. `Pitch = X rotation`, `Yaw = Y rotation`,`Roll = Z rotation`.

Comment: So your example rolls -5 radians around z-axis?

Comment: This value is in degrees. (Cmd-click `.rollAroundTarget(-5)` and choose `Jump to Definition`)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the camera's rotation axis to be the center of a node, you can use the code below:

```
if let worldCenter = self.localToWorld(point: node.boundingSphere.center) {
    let newWorldPosition = SCNVector3(worldCenter.x, worldCenter.y, worldCenter.z + 5.0)
    self.sceneView.pointOfView?.position = newWorldPosition
    self.sceneView.defaultCameraController.target = worldCenter
}

func localToWorld(localPoint: SCNVector3) {
     // node is the object you want the camera to rotate around its center
     node.convertVector(localPoint, to: nil)
}
```